# Robocopy to AWS Fileshare access denied errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, robocopy, fileshare

no matter what i do, i get accessed denied when trying to use Robocopy to move SQL backups off of a windows server to an AWS SMB Fileshare.

I am running the robocopy command on the sql server. Ive verified i am the "owner" of the folder within the AWS fileshare as well as have full access. its the same with the source folder as well. i am not sure what else to try here to get this to work. the percentage starts and percentage runs to about 10% then throws the access denied errors.

below is the command i was running. ive tired with /b or /dcopy:DT

robocopy.exe "E:\backups" "\\server IP\test" /mov /MT:16

ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File E:\backups\1.bak
Access is denied.

tried many different robocopy flags.

i also tried to just use SQL native backup directly to the AWS fileshare and it runs and its about 10% then gives an access denied error.

Comment: "Error 5" is a generic access denied, break the problem apart and test the peices. Can you robocopy from e:\backups to e:\tempbackups (or some local location that exists)? Can you map a drive in explorer and copy the files manually? I assume `"\server IP\test"` is really `"\\server IP\test"`?

Comment: i can robocopy without deleting fine. its when it gets to the deletion portion it fails. I can also copy them manually drag and drop between the two. You are correct in the assumption, ill fix it in the original post.

Comment: something just weird with the files. I created a text document on the same source directory and ran the robocopy command and specified that text document. moved no issue and removed from the source directory. I went under one of the files i am getting errors from and added full control to the user, and it ended up moving and deleted as expected without issue. But i am logged in as an admin, the files owner is the same admin account i am logged in as. I am not sure where the permission issue lies.